Necessity of Privacy Manifest and Signature for third-party SDK in app review
As I can understand about privacy manifest for Apple, if I don't have PrivacyInfo in my third-party library, I can create PrivacyInfo myself in my app project and add the details for a third-party library.
But my question is, My third-party library is too old and did not provide updates(privacy manifest and signature). And if I add details of that library into my app's privacy manifest. But how I can create a signature for that third-party library or what should I have to do for that?
Need more clarification for the old third-party library which could not provide a privacy manifest and signature. Then how can proceed without that old library's signature?

Nothing You just have to create Privacy File in your main target app and mention what ever your thirdparty sdk is doing. That's it no need for signature or anything.

The only SDKs that are required to provide signatures are the ones listed in the following Apple document:
https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/
If it is not in the list, it is not required.
It is easy enough to sign all frameworks yourself.  You might already be doing it when you sign your app.

Got your point. One last thing. If the framework is old and in the list. But I do not want to update it to the latest one. Will manage the privacy manifest things in my app's manifest. But how can sign that framework? Do you have any links? So, kindly provide.
